# Call VB method in C# using Interop

Tags: c#, vba, interop

Okey here's the situation: I've got a microsoft excel macro in vb that I want to call using C#. I've already tried creating a workbook using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, however I don't want to have to run an excel process to run the macro.

So then I thought why not make a vb class library with my code in it so i can still run it and have a clean dll file. It's not needed to keep any sheet related functions since the macro reads a .lua(UTF-8)text file with some advanced regex functions that I just can't get recreated in C#.

Is it possible for me to make the library use interop as well so i can just call the function in my C#? Any examples would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which compiler do you have available?

Comment: the standard visual studio 2010 compiler is what i'm going to use.

Answer (score 0):

First I assume you are working with VB6 and not VB Script?

I have never worked with VB 6 or earlier, but I think your best be will be to create a COM object and then you can call the COM object from .NET using C#. Here is a quick link I found through BING that I believe will help you get started if this in an option for you.

**[Walkthrough: Implementing Inheritance with COM Objects (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2044hysa.aspx)**

Comment: Yes it's VBA which is a slightly different version of VB 6 I'll have a look and tell you how things work out.

Comment: @OhBugger, I thought you might be refering to VBA, but when you mentioned creating a class library I thought you might be refering to VB6. Well good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed these two statements:

> I don't want to have to run an excel process to run the macro

and

> the macro reads a .lua(UTF-8)text file with some advanced regex functions that I just can't get recreated in C#

Those two goals are incompatible. The macro relies on excel functions to run. The only way provided by Microsoft to accomplish this is to completely load the Excel app. There is no way to only run the macro.